# Creating a 3-way join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails. I am trying to create a table that is a combination of three tables. So I have a subject table, a period table, and a teacher table. I would like to create one Class table that is a combination of a subject, period, and teacher. How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a migration like this:

**EDIT: When using `belongs_to` inside a table creation block, you should use the association name instead of the column name**

```
def self.up
  create_table :school_classes do |t|
    t.belongs_to :subject
    t.belongs_to :teacher
    t.belongs_to :period

    #any_other_columns_required
  end

  add_index :school_classes, [:subject_id, :teacher_id, :period_id], :unique => true
end

def self.down
  drop_table :school_classes
end
```

Comment: This is probably very obvious, but I'm very new to rails. Would I just create a new table like SchoolClasses.create or SchoolClasses.create(:subject_id => Subject.first, :teacher_id => Teacher.first, :period_id => Period.first)

Comment: I get this when I create that migration `SQLite3::SQLException: table classrooms has no column named subject_id: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "classroom_index" ON "classrooms" ("subject_id", "teacher_id", "period_id")`

Comment: @matthew Oh, sorry that was my mistake. Roll back your migration and then edit it so it looks like my recently edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, I had been trying to create a table like this for a couple of days now!

Answer (score 4):

I would call it `Classroom` (Class might conflict with something)

Then in that table insert columns teacher_id, subject_id, and period_id. In your Classroom model, you would write

```
belongs_to :teacher
belongs_to :subject
belongs_to :period
```

And in the teacher, subject, and period model you would write

```
has_many :classrooms
```

Comment: How would I create a new Classroom, through Classroom.create or Classroom.create(:subject_id => Subject.first, :teacher_id => Teacher.first, :period_id => Period.first)

Comment: through Classroom.create. In the new Classroom page, you'll want to input which teacher/period/subject id you want tied to that classroom. Did you generate the view pages?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible for different pairs (subject and teacher) to have the same period, there is no need to create another table. In this case the period table might be the linking table:

```
class Period
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :subject
  ...

class Teacher
  has_many :periods
  has_many :subjects, through: :periods
  ...

class Subject
  has_many :periods
  has_many :teachers, through: :periods
  ...
```

I repeat, you can go this way only if the same period can't be using by different pairs of other models. For example, if you have just one room and only one pair can study in this room at the same time (use period), and information you store in Period table is uniq for each study.